# Refactor/extract JavaScript string in Visual Studio Code into an HTML file

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a project that uses a lot of template strings, that I want to convert to separate HTML files.

I know Visual Studio Code can move JavaScript to a new file. Can it do the same with HTML string content?

The closest I can do is extract the JavaScript string to a new file, and then rename it and change the extension.

I've not found an issue in the Visual Studio Code GitHub account or any other questions about this.

So I want to go from this:

```
const MY_TEMPLATE = `<div>{{unicorn.fart()}}</div>`
function useTemplate(imports){
    return {
        template: MY_TEMPLATE,
        scope: {
            unicorn: imports.getUnicorn('charlie')
            onFart: imports.refuelCar(imports.ELECTRIC_CAR)
        }
    }
}
```

Highlight the string in the `MY_TEMPLATE` select a right click menu, and then get this:

```
import template from './MY_TEMPLATE.html'
function useTemplate(imports){
    return {
        template,
        scope: {
            unicorn: imports.getUnicorn('charlie')
            onFart: imports.refuelCar(imports.ELECTRIC_CAR)
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a setting to change, a version to install/wait for or a plugin?

Answer (score 1):

This does not exist as of Visual Studio Code 1.29. Since this is a very specific feature request, and it would best be implemented by an extension and not as part of core Visual Studio Code.

See [this guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/overview) for information on how to get started writing a Visual Studio Code extension.